# Windows 10 free upgrade vs. paid

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have read in both Tech Republic and PC World articles that the free Windows 10 upgrade has ads in (at least) solitaire. I'm guessing it has ads in other apps, as well. Does anyone know if the paid version also has ads? It would really suck if that were the case.

Comment: There is no difference between the free upgrade, which is only free until July 29 2016, and buying the upgrade on July 30 2016. The Solitaire in Windows 10 will have ads no matter what.

Comment: I'm just curious why the downvote. It seems like a legitimate question. Of course, if I had been able to install the upgrade, I would know the answer to this, but alas, I will have to do a clean install to get Windows 10.

Comment: Doing a clean install before doing an upgrade will result in an installation that cannot be activated as for the downvote this question has been asked numerous times, the underline question, with regards to the free upgrade vs a paid upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found no ads in my free upgrade of windows 10. I believe that the solitaire app is no-longer made my Microsoft and so may have ads because it is free. Other apps will have apps but not any made by Microsoft. For example the weather/news/money apps that come installed by default do not have ads.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 is Windows 10, no matter where you get it. All independent versions (home, pro, ect...) have their own set of features, but there is no difference between the version you can buy, and the version you can upgrade to. Ads have been integrated into many Microsoft services, including Skype, Solitaire, and Office 365.